# Error in vaadin 6

Tags: eclipse, browser, render, vaadin, browser-cache

I created a project in Vaadin 6 and ran it. It renders the text 'Hello Vaadin user' in browser perfectly.

Then I changed the label message.

```
public void init() {
    Window mainWindow = new Window("Edojimav6 Application");
    Label label = new Label("Vaadin 6"); // changed text
    mainWindow.addComponent(label);
    setMainWindow(mainWindow);
}
```

But it still displays the same text on browser 'Hello Vaadin user' and I cleared browsing history(cookies, cache memory.. But, I cleared everything) in my browser and ran the code. Now it renders the text 'Vaadin 6' perfectly.

Each and every time I need to clear browser history to run my code. I have proxy settings enabled in my network.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo. I have tested in Chrome 24.0.1312.57, Firefox 15.0.1 and Safari 6.0 browsers.

But, Vaadin 7 runs perfectly. It does not require any 'History clearing' to run the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vaadin 6, you have to add ?restartApplication to the url of the application, for example

```
 http://localhost:8080/myapp?restartApplication
```

Comment: Great.. It worked for me. Is that mandatory to add '?restartApplicatio n' or else it is a fix for any bug..